# Bean Validation to check for one of a few integer values

Tags: java, integer, bean-validation

Using [Jakarta Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/) versions 2 or 3, how can I check that an `int` or `Integer` member field has one of a limited set of values?

For a contrived over-simplified example, consider this [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) representing a barrel with a field for capacity that should hold either 50 or 55.

```java
record Barrel ( 
    UUID id , 
    int capacity   // Constrain to a value of either 50 or 55. 
) {}
```

➥ How would I annotate that `capacity` field to ensure it has only `50` or `55` as its numeric value?

If the `capacity` field were of type `String`, I could use `@Pattern` with a regex.

```java
public record Barrel(
    @NotNull 
    UUID id , 
    @NotNull 
    @Pattern ( regexp = "50|55" )  // Constrain to a value of either "50" or "55". 
    String capacity
) {}
```

Running it.

```java
package work.basil.example.beanval;

import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import jakarta.validation.Validation;
import jakarta.validation.Validator;
import jakarta.validation.ValidatorFactory;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        Barrel barrel = new Barrel( UUID.fromString( "e78456ac-6f12-45ae-b8e1-c3b8193a920e" ) , "55" );
        Set < ConstraintViolation < Barrel > > violations = validator.validate( barrel );
        System.out.format( "INFO - Found %d violations.\n" , violations.size() );
        violations.forEach( barrelConstraintViolation -> System.out.println( barrelConstraintViolation.getMessage() ) );
    }
}
```

➥ How can I get the same effect for an `int`/`Integer` as for a `String`?

Comment: I think you'll need to write your own `@Constraint`. That would let you make your annotation parameter an `int[]`.

Comment: I second the comment above - you will have to write it on your own, and it is fairly trivial, imo. We have _lots_ of these custom validators too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in validator for that. Building your own is trivial though:

1. Add the constraint annotation:

   ```
    import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
    import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
    import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

    import javax.validation.Constraint;
    import javax.validation.Payload;
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.Target;

    @Target({FIELD,PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Constraint(validatedBy = OneOfValidator.class)
    public @interface OneOf {

        String message() default "...provide your default message here...";

        Class<?>[] groups() default { };

        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

        /** The array of allowed values. */
        int[] value();
    }
   ```

   Note that it references the actual validator class (see below) and you have to provide an appropriate validation message.
2. Create the validator logic:

   ```
    import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

    import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
    import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class OneOfValidator implements ConstraintValidator<OneOf, Integer> {

        private Set<Integer> allowedValues;

        @Override
        public void initialize(OneOf constraintAnnotation) {
            allowedValues = Arrays.stream(constraintAnnotation.value()).boxed().collect(toSet());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Integer i, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
            return i == null || allowedValues.contains(i);
        }
    }
   ```
3. Use:

   ```
    @OneOf({50,55})
    int capacity;
   ```

Note: For a use case such as yours, could an `enum` be more appropriate?

Comment: The use-case in my Question is contrived for simplicity. An Enum would be appropriate for that. My real-world use-case needs more flexibility than an Enum can provide. Thank you for your Answer and sample code.